# open Safari and Finder failed in tmux

Tags: macos, finder, tmux, safari, osx-mavericks

OS X 10.9.2, tmux 1.9a install via brew. In tmux:

```
$ open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app                                                                                                                           
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app.
$ open /Applications/Safari.app                                                                                                                                          
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Applications/Safari.app.
$ open /Applications/Xcode.app
(Success)
```

Out tmux:

```
$ open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app                                                                                                                           
(Success)
$ open /Applications/Safari.app                                                                                                                                          
(Success)
$ open /Applications/Xcode.app
(Success)
```

What causes this problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: I have similar issue with tmux 1.9a, but a different error code (- 10810). I restarted tmux and it started working again. This could be a bug in tmux.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting tmux does seem to fix this problem for me as well. Not sure why, but will edit my answer if I stumble upon the cause.

Comment: Same here. I'm using `tmux` 2.7 and [`tmux-pasteboard`](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) 2.6 (AKA `reattach-to-user-namespace`) from Macports. I could only get the problem to go away after restarting `tmux` and waiting a while. Very strange stuff.

Comment: Seems to happen if you log out then back in but reattach to an existing tmux session from pre-log out. Maybe some env var in the tmux session is set to an invalid value.